# XSLT 2.0 Help Required - group By,Sum,ReplaceString

Tags: xml, xslt

Need help on XSLT 2.0 mapping based on grouping of employee-id. XML file will be generated by summing up the amount and hours by grouping of employee id.
Amount - "#" means a positive number where as "#(" means a negative number. 
Hours - this will be summation of time duration.

I did not try with Hours but tried with Amount except the characters(#,#(, also not tried in case it has blank value) and it is working. Need your help and expertise in completing the same.

## Input Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Employees>
 <Employee>
  <Amount>#1,424.85</Amount>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Surname>Shibob</Surname>
  <Hours>24:20</Hours>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <Amount>#(1,424.85</Amount>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Surname>Shibob</Surname>
  <Hours>56:00</Hours>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <Amount>#70</Amount>
  <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
  <Name>Sara</Name>
  <Surname>Lee</Surname>
  <Hours>57.30</Hours>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <Amount>#(1,001.20</Amount>
  <EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Surname>Smith</Surname>
  <Hours></Hours>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <Amount></Amount>
  <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
  <Name>Penny</Name>
  <Surname>Wise</Surname>
  <Hours>56:59</Hours>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <Amount>#(.30</Amount>
  <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
  <Name>Penny</Name>
  <Surname>Wise</Surname>
  <Hours>26:03</Hours>
 </Employee>
</Employees>
```

### My XSLT Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Define keys used to group elements -->
    <xsl:key name="keyEmployeeID" match="Employee" use="EmployeeID" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <Employees>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Employee[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyEmployeeID', EmployeeID)[1])]">
    <Employee>
     <xsl:variable name="empID">.
    <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID" /></xsl:variable>
     <EmployeeID><xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID" /></EmployeeID>

     <Name1><xsl:value-of select="//Employee[EmployeeID=$empID]/Name" /></Name1>
     <Surname><xsl:value-of select="//Employee[EmployeeID=$empID]/Surname" /></Surname>
    <!-- Show the total Amount for the current Employee -->
    <code><xsl:value-of select="sum(//Employee[EmployeeID=$empID]/Amount)" /></code>
    </Employee>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Employees>   
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you confirm you can only use XSLT 1.0? The task would be much easier if you could use XSLT 2.0 or above? Thanks!

Comment: Always tag XSLT questions with a specific version number, especially if they require facilities like grouping or regular expressions that are new in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Apologies, I can use XSLT 2.0 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of strange data in there, there some empty `Hours` or `Amount` elements, I have chosen to ignore them when summing values. Additionally you have not told us exactly which input format you have and which result format you want, I have simply tried to assume the `Hours` are in some format `hh:mm` and can be converted to an `xs:dayTimeDuration` in the format `PThhHmmM' and you then want to sum those durations and output them as durations:

```
  <xsl:template match="Employees">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-by="EmployeeID">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="EmployeeID, Name, Surname"/>
                  <code>
                      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount[normalize-space()]/xs:decimal(replace(replace(., '[#,]', ''), '\(', '-')))"/>
                  </code>
                  <hours>
                      <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Hours[normalize-space()]/xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT', replace(., '([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})', '$1H$2M'))))"/>
                  </hours>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzT has a sample.

Comment: XSLT Version should be 2.0 with Saxon HE 9.5.1.5 for my case. Sorry, I should mention the result format as well. Hours should be shown as HH:MM format Only.

Comment: The snippet shown above is XSLT 2, the linked example uses XSLT 3 but for XSLT 2 you just have to replace the used `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template. To format the computed sums or the computed durations in a particular format I think you should ask new, separate questions if you can't work it out yourself with the help of the XSLT and XPath function reference like https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/.